# How to implement a socket client from node

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have a socket implementation that works fine with the socket server running in node js and socket client running in the browser with vue.

The problem is that I'm trying to implement a new client from a different node js project but with no success.

Am I missing anything? Please help!

I've followed the link but still can't make it work. https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client

**Server.js**

```
const Socketio = require('socket.io')(Http)
Socketio.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('join_room', function (room) {
    console.log('join room -> ', room)
    socket.join(room)
  })
}

Http.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('sockets listening at : 3000')
})
```

**Client - Browser - Vue**

```
 created() {
   this.socket = io('http://localhost:3000')
   this.socket.on('connect', () => {
   console.log("its connected")
     this.socket.emit('join_room', this.id)
   })
 }
```

**Node Js CLient**

```
    var io = require('socket.io-client');
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000', { reconnect: true });
   
    socket.on('connect', () => {
        console.log("it never logs here, and it doesn't emit join room either");
        socket.emit('join_room', id)
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect first:

```
  var io = require('socket.io-client');
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000', { reconnect: true }); // here you forget to make a connexion 

socket.on('connect', () => {
    console.log("it never logs here, and it doesn't emit join room either");
    socket.emit('join_room', id)
});
```

Comment: Implement this code the see if any error appear:  ` socket.on('error', (error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });`

Comment: you mean on client side, right?
nothing happens.

Updated the question to add the io.connect